# How to set/call angularJS variable from HTML

Tags: angularjs, function, variables, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use AngularJS to set variables on the App level and then call them throughout the files for a page.

I am trying to set hard coded numbers to pass to the functions in the scripts.  I can get the page to generate, so I know that the actual javascript code is working, but I don't seem to have the right syntax to set/call the variables in the HTML file.

So what is the correct syntax for setting the values so that I can reference them?
So what is the correct syntax for referencing the values to pass into the function?

Below are the reduced files for reference.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="./App.js" runat="server">
            vApp.value("vPage", "0");
            vApp.value("vLevel", "0");
            vApp.value("vDivision", "0");
            vApp.value("vLayout", "./Layout.html");
        </script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="./Universal.js" runat="server"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="./Layout.js" runat="server"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="./Custom.js" runat="server"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="idBody" ng-app="vApp">
        <any ng-include src="'Layout.html'"></any>
    </body>
</html>
```

Layout.html

```
    <any ng-controller="CustomController" ng-bind-html="getContent($rootScope.vPage)"></any>
```

App.js

```
var vApp = angular.module("vApp", []);
```

Custom.js

```
    vApp.controller("CustomController", ['$scope', '$sce', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $sce, $rootScope, vPage)
{
    $scope.getContent = function(vPage)
    {
        $scope.vResult = "";
        $scope.vDefault = "";

        $scope.vDefault += "Zero";

        $scope.vResult += "<p id='idCenterContent'>";
            if(vPage == 0)
            {
                $scope.vResult += $scope.vDefault;
            }
            else if(vPage == 1)
            {
                $scope.vResult += "One";

            }
            else if(vPage == 2)
            {
                $scope.vResult += "Two";

            }
            else if(vPage == 3)
            {
                $scope.vResult += "Three";

            }
            else
            {
                $scope.vResult += $scope.vDefault;
            }

        $scope.vResult += "</p>";

        return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.vResult);
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally managed to learn enough to simulate what I was attempting to do by storing the page, level, and division on the UniversalController and removing all the parameters.

The variables are set by the initial HTML page:

```
<script language="JavaScript" runat="server">
        {{vPage = 0;""}}
        {{vLevel = 0;""}}
        {{vDivision = 0;""}}
    </script>
```